# C++ file handling

Tags: c++, file-handling

I have two text files "source1" and "source2" that contain integers *3 4 1 2 56* and *2 45 34 23 45* respectively.

Displaying them on the screen.

*Even though there is not any error given but what i am sure is that those array isn't getting the correct data from the files source1 and source2.*

*The ouput should be the integers in the file but it's not what i expected.*

[image: The ouput should be the integers int the file but it's not what i expected.]

i guess there is some problem with my READ and WRITE.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<fstream>
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;


 int main()
{
     fstream file1;
     fstream file2;
     file1.open("source1.txt");
     file2.open("source2.txt");
     int source1[20];
     int source2[20];
     file1.read((char*)&source1,sizeof(source1));
     cout<<source1<<"\n";
     file2.read((char*)&source2,sizeof(source2));
     cout<<source2<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: try opening your file and then reading data as `int data; file1>>data`and put it in a loop that ends with file.

Comment: I want to do it with read and write only @AbhinavGauniyal

Answer (score 3):

Here are some issues I noticed with your program.

### Reading Arrays

Your code reads in 20 integers, whether there are 20 or not.  If the file contains 4 binary integers, how do you handle the error?

Your file ends with a `.txt` extension, so I assume the data is in human readable (text) format.  The `read` method does not translate "123" into the number `123`.  The `read` method will save a *mirror* of the data, as is.

### Arrays and `cout`

The C++ programming language's `cout` does not have facilities for printing arrays of integers.  You'll have to use a loop to print them.  Also, you should use a separator between the integers, such as tab, newline, comma or space.

### Binary & Text writing

If you want to write the internal representation of a number, use `ostream::write`.  If you want to use formatted or textual representation use `operator>>`.
If the integer is more than a byte wide you will need to know if the platform outputs the highest byte first (Big Endian) or last (Little Endian).  This makes a big difference when you read the values back.

### Use Vectors not Arrays

Vectors are easier to pass and they take care of dynamic growth.  Arrays are fixed capacity by definition and require 3 parameters when passing:  The array, the capacity, and the quantity of items in the array.  With `std::vector`, only the vector needs to be passed because all the other information can be obtained by calling `vector` methods, such as `vector::size()`.

Answer (score 0):

When opening files in C or C++ to write binary data, you have to open them in binary mode. Use:

```
 file1.open("source1.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
 file2.open("source2.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
```

Or similar flags.

Comment: I tried this but still nothing happens.
Some random figures are being generated.

Comment: Are you sure that `target` contains the right data after your sorting is done?  It is not clear by your question whether the problem is the fie writing, or the actual data that you're supposed to write.

Comment: OP has txt files I guess :O  `"integers 3 4 1 2 56 and 2 45 34 23 45 "`with integers in them

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i am merging the data of two source files into the target file.
the problem is that i ain't getting the right output.

Comment: @Tilakraj So again, is the problem with the array containing the wrong data, or is it the problem with the file writing?  You still haven't clarified this.

Comment: The problem comes after the read statement.Even though there is not any error given but what i am sure is that those array isn't getting the correct data from the files _source1_ and _source2_

Comment: So, how do I use `file1.open` in the C language?  Is there a structure I can reference?  Normally, in C, I would use `fopen`.

Comment: @Tilakraj Well I suggest you write a very small program that reads integers from a file and get that to work first.  Your question is mixing in things that have nothing to do with the problem at hand (for example, merge sort).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How about now ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code that describes what you are trying to achieve:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

bool readIntsFromFile( const std::string& strFilename, std::vector<int>& v ) {
    std::fstream inFile;
    inFile.open( strFilename.c_str(), std::ios_base::in );
    if ( !inFile.is_open() ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        int val;
        while ( !inFile.eof() ) {
            inFile >> val;
            v.push_back( val );
        }
    }
    inFile.close();

    return true;
}

void sortVectors( const std::vector<int>& v1, const std::vector<int>& v2, std::vector<int>& out ) {
    unsigned index = 0;
    for ( ; index < v1.size(); ++index ) {
        out.push_back( v1[index] );
    }

    index = 0;
    for ( ; index < v2.size(); ++index ) {
        out.push_back( v2[index] );
    }

    std::sort( out.begin(), out.end() );
}

int main() {
    const std::string strFile1( "source1.txt" );
    const std::string strFile2( "source2.txt" );
    const std::string strOutput( "output.txt" );

    std::vector<int> a;
    std::vector<int> b;
    std::vector<int> res;

    if ( !readIntsFromFile( strFile1, a ) ) {
        return -1;
    }

    if ( !readIntsFromFile( strFile2, b ) ) {
        return -1;
    }

    sortVectors( a, b, res );

    unsigned index = 0;
    for ( ; index < res.size(); ++index ) {
        std::cout << res[index] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::fstream out;
    out.open( strOutput.c_str(), std::ios_base::out );
    if ( !out.is_open() ) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        index = 0;
        for ( ; index < res.size(); ++index ) {
            out << res[index] << " ";
        }
    }
    out.close();

    return 0; 
}
```

Just make sure that your source1 & source2 text files are in the same directory
as your generated executable.